# .NET Framework 4.0/4.5: Microsoft wants to confuse me?

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I have several Windows 2008 R2 servers where "Programs and Features" claims that .NET Framework 4.5 is installed.

However, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64 does not list a 4.5 but a 4.0 (which is not mentioned in Programs and Features). In it are DLLs versioned 4.0 and a csc.exe that claims to be

> Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 4.0.30319.17929 for Microsoft
>   (R) .NET Framework 4.5

Is Microsoft just trying to confuse me or am I overlooking something? Which version of the framework is installed and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude. .NET 4.5 is an in place upgrade to 4.0 - as such the folders still are 4.0. As are a lot of assembly versions for compatibility reasons. Not the first time MS does that.

Answer (score 1):

[Compatibility of .NET Framework 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/09/26/compatibility-of-net-framework-4-5.aspx) explains:

> .NET Framework 4.5 is an in-place update that replaces .NET Framework 4 (rather than a side-by-side installation). ... One of the first things you’ll notice about .NET 4.5 is the version number (4.0.30319) is the same as .NET 4; this is the practice used by other in-place updates.

[.NET 4.5 is an in-place replacement for .NET 4.0](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/13/NET-45-is-an-inplace-replacement-for-NET-40) provides a detailed examination of version numbers, DLLs, and configuration between 4.0 and 4.5.